# How can two threads be "in" a "synchronized" method

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm really a new at Java concurrency and I'm trying to implement the following specifications:

- We have a car park which has some park spots
- Each car is represented as a thread which endlessy change the car state from Driving - Parking. Each car has his own parking spot.
- When the car is in the parking state, it tries to park in a spot (no necessary his spot). If the spot is free then it parks else it will skip this parking phase and go back to drive.
- The car remains in the spot unless the owner of the spot want to park.

This is not the exact specification, but the only problem that I have is the following:

I'm not able to make the car skip the turn. If two cars pick the same spots, then one is parked and the other is waiting until the park is free. Which is not the bahvior that I want.
My first idea was to simply synchronize the read and write to a variable occupied:

```
class Car implements Runnable {
    private CarState state = CarState.driving

    run {
        while(true) {
            switch(state) {
            case driving: 
                System.out.println(this + " driving.");
                state = parking;
                break;
            case parking: Spot s = CarPark.getRandomSpot();

                if(s.willingToPark(this)) {
                    System.out.println(s + " occupied. " + this 
                    + " skip park turn.");
                } else {
                    s.park(this);
                } 
                state = driving;
            }
        }

    }
}

class Spot {
    private boolean occupied = false;
    private Car owner = new Car(...);

    synchronized boolean willingToPark(Car c) {
        if(occupied) {
            return true;
        } else {
            occupied = true;
            return false;
    }

    synchronized void park(Car c) {
        System.out.println(c + " parking at " + this);
        //don't care how this is implemented, just keep in mind
        //that it will enter in a loop until the owner came back.
        occupied = false;
    }
}
```

If I run this with three cars, then I will end up in having car0 is parking at spot1, car1 is parking at spot0, car2 is waiting on spot0, because car1 is executing the synchronized block park(Car c). I don't get how is it possible that two cars can park in the same spot if the willingToPark is synchronized.

Thank you

Comment: Thanks for the pleasant surprise. When I saw the title and opening sentences, I was not expecting a well-phrased question.

Comment: I think you should have a reference in Spot class to the car that is currently in that Spot, so when the owner of this spot wants to park you can notify the car that is currently parking that it has to drive and make room for the owner.

Comment: can you show your main method that runs cars? how do you change car states? based on given info it is not obvious why cars are locked on willingToPark method

Comment: You could create  a while loop in your Car run method, that continues to iterate until the car is parked. If the car attempts to park in a spot that is already occupied, then just use "continue" and look for another spot. The problem you are having is that your synchronized method just forces threads to wait until that resource (your spot) is free. This means if you have 2 cars (A and B), they both want to park in the same spot and the other will wait on that resource until the car leaves.

Comment: Hello Keammoort, thank you for the reply, but the problem is not there. The problem is when two cars tru to park in the same spot. One of the two must park, while the other must skip this park turn and return to drive.

Comment: the implementation of park is quite important. When you really just iterate in the park method, the spot object is blocked because park is synchronized. So no other car can enter this spot for any synchronized method. But if you implement it with the wait method, it wouldn't block other cars in that way.

Comment: @Evan Bechtol. I don't think this is the case, because the willingToPark is separated from the park method. So, theorically car B can enter the willingToPark since car A cannot be blocked there.

Comment: @Typishserg. Wai I'm getting wrong the synchronized word? I mean, if a car is keeping the lock for the park method, another car can enter the willingToPark right?

Comment: @AdamSkywalker. The main method for the cars is run, which changes the states. Actually I made a mistake and forgot the while(true)

Comment: @LucaDotti If your car is parked, will it always be in the "parking" state? If it is, then a single thread could potentially keep calling the willingToPark method, which is synchronized, causing your other threads to be blocked.

Comment: @LucaDotti I still don't see a condition that changes car state to parking

Comment: @AdamSkywalker Yes forgot them. Updated the code

Comment: shouldn't you only change your state to driving if it failed to park?

Comment: @LucaDotti I think it's important to note that you are never freeing up the spaces that are considered occupied, but you are changing the car state to driving after it parks. Is this desired behavior?

Comment: @Evan Bechtol In the park method, the occupied flag will be set to false.

Comment: Probably a minor thing, but it looks like your "if" is backwards. Right now it says "if willing to park, skip, else park."

Comment: @WalterM No, because if the the park method return, means that the owner of the current spot is returned, so the car return to drive.

Comment: @yshavit The method name is not really correct, but it return true when the spot is occupied and false otherwise.

Comment: @LucaDotti It looks like all the booleans are backwards at first glance. When a thread grabs the lock for one of the `synchronized` methods, none of the other `synchronized` methods are available to other threads...

Comment: @Mad Physicist That's exactly what I misunderstood. Thank you

Comment: Using a lock-free approach (in the manner that @S.D. suggests in their answer) is a very good alternative to synchronization.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I don't get how is it possible that two cars can park in the same spot
>   if the willingToPark is synchronized.

It's actually simple. **Car1** captures **spot0** and starts waiting for owner in a loop inside `park()` method (you did not provide the code). While it is waiting, it owns monitor and does not allow anyone to call synchronized methods on **spot0**.
 That is the reason why **car2** hangs on `willingToPark()` method.

Comment: Ahhh so I got wrong the synchronized. So I need two locks, one which is the spot itself for the park method and one for the willingToPark

Comment: No actually, I cannot use the spot object as lock.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the looping of `park`. Imagine this:

- Two threads both grab the same Spot, `s`.
- They both try to acquire the monitor lock on `s`; only one will succeed.
- The one that succeeds will cause `park` to spin, *while still holding the lock*.
- The other one patiently waits until the lock is released, so that it can try to acquire it.

There's nothing (short of killing the JVM) that will tell the thread that failed to park, to stop waiting on `s`. It'll wait until it can acquire the lock -- which will only happen once the first thread finishes the loop on `park`.

The solution is not to loop in `park` at all. Instead, the *Car* should unset the `occupied` flag, via a new method `unpark(Car)`. This method must also be synchronized, for the sake of memory visibility across threads.

Now the data flow looks like:

- Two threads both grab the same Spot, `s`.
- They both try to acquire the monitor lock on `s`; only one will succeed.
- The one that succeeds sets `occupied = true`, and immediately returns and then releases the lock on `s`
- The other one acquires the lock on `s`, and sees that the spot is occupied.

Incidentally, you don't even need a `synchronized` method for this. You can use an AtomicBoolean's [compareAndSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html#compareAndSet-boolean-boolean-) method, which lets you atomically check the AtomicBoolean's value, and only set it if its current value is what you expect it to be. Thus, `return occupied.compareAndSet(false, true)` means "atomically check the current value; if it's false, then set it to true and return true; if it's true, then keep it as it is, and return false." This kind of behavior is useful, but a bit more advanced.

Answer (score 2):

Flag the parking spots with an [AtomicBoolean](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html#set%28boolean%29):

```
class Spot{
  public final AtomicBoolean flag = new AtomicBoolean(false);
}
```

Some where else in code, there is a race among car threads to grab the spots:

```
if(spot.flag.compareAndSet(false,true)){
  // spot owned by current thread !!
  // for other threads, `compareAndSet` will fail because they expect it to be `false`.

  // visit store and buy stuff while car is parked.

  // time to go, release the spot
  spot.flag.set(false);
}else{
  // find another spot
}
```

Full Example:  http://ideone.com/dw3LnV

This approach is wait free and lock free, You can put spot contest logic in a while loop and threads will keep contending for the flag.

Further reading: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp11234/

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't get the big picture about synchronization, Luca. The waiting loop is the problem. As for synchronization itself, it can be done on objects only:

- having a method `synchronized` makes it synchronized on `this`
- having a block of code `synchronized(someObject) {...}` makes it synchronized on `someObject`

When a synchronized method is called, it doesn't allow any other synchronized method use the object it is synchronized on. So by using that loop, you locked everything else out. As others stated, you should only use synchronization for the shortest possible to do the task.

You can, for example, synchronize just the unparking part in the park method:

```
void park(Car c) {
    System.out.println(c + " parking at " + this);
    //don't care how this is implemented, just keep in mind
    //that it will enter in a loop until the owner came back.
    synchronized (this) {
        occupied = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello thank you. Yes that was exaclty my missunderstanding!

Comment: Feel free to mark this as an answer of your question if it answers it. Adam pointed out the problem with loop, but I don't think he gave you a solution.